# How do I access a value from a JSON string?

Tags: ruby, json

I have a variable.  When I do `puts var_name` I get this hash:

```
"{\"numConnections\": 163}"
```

But when I try to get that number 163 from the value `numConnections` it isn't working. Here is what I am trying:

```
connections = temp_var["\"numConnections\""]
puts connections.inspect
```

or:

```
connections = temp_var["numConnections"]
puts connections.inspect
```

both of which equally don't work.

Any idea how to extract that 163 from there?

Comment: That doesn't look like a hash, it looks like a string. What does `var_name.class` return?

Comment: Print the type of temp_var, I am quite sure it's not a hash at all but a string. Looks like JSON to me?

Comment: Hmmm, I see....good point. Is there any easy way to extract the value by doing some function meant to deal with json?

Comment: `require "json"; hash = JSON.parse(your_variable); hash["numConnections"]`

Comment: @dominikh yeah that did it! Thanks! If you want to, you can put it as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a JSON string, you need to parse it into a hash before you can use it to access its keys and values in a hash-like way. Consider this IRB session:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'json'
 => true
1.9.3p194 :002 > temp_var = "{\"numConnections\": 163}"
 => "{"numConnections": 163}"
1.9.3p194 :003 > temp_var.class
 => String 
1.9.3p194 :004 > JSON.parse(temp_var)
 => {"numConnections"=>163}
1.9.3p194 :005 > JSON.parse(temp_var)['numConnections']
 => 163
```