# parse json to get field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to get json value from below json response but couldn't able to get it. Could you please advise me?

```
[   
 {     
  "name": test
  "id": 123    
 } 
]
```

I have tried below code to get value for name.

```
response.body["name"]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's not valid json.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see what you've tried toward solving your problem. Parsing JSON and accessing the resulting object is *extremely* well documented, both here on Stack Overflow, on the internet, and in the documentation. [ask].

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10804020/128421.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON: "test" isn't in a string, and you're missing a comma.  If it was valid JSON, for example like this:

```
json = "[{\"name\": \"test\", \"id\": 123}]"
```

You could turn it into a Ruby data structure:

```
arr = JSON.parse(json)
=> [{"name"=>"test", "id"=>123}]
```

and then extract the name:

```
name = arr.first["name"]
```

Comment: Thanks Max, yes it was my fault writing Json file here. Now I got error while parsing json arr = JSON.parse(json) --> no implicit conversion of Unirest::HttpResponse into String.

Comment: You need to mention this sort of thing in your question, eg how you are getting the json response in the first place.  We're not mind readers...

Comment: Try calling `body` on your response and see what you get.  It will probably be a string but might get parsed into a hash automatically.